# How to integrate a conductive adhesive sensor

Tags: circuit-design, sensor, wiring, conductive, adhesives

I am working on my final project for uni, in which I am building an electrical circuit using a force sensor that has conductive adhesive. I am unsure how to integrate this sensor into my circuit, meaning I am unsure how to connect wires to it since I have never worked with a sensor like this before.
Would really appreciate any suggestions.
P.S: I have attached a photo of the sensor, the sensor is called "4-Zone FSR" made by INTERLINK.[image: 4-Zone FSR Sensor]

Comment: Don't be afraid to email the manufacturer.

Comment: (1) https://www.interlinkelectronics.com/4-zone-fsr, (2) https://www.interlinkelectronics.com/4-zone-fsr-hdk

Comment: a zebra connector with a suitable clamp may work

Comment: Refer to the [Integration Guide](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3899023/Interlinkelectronics%20November2017/Docs/4ZoneMouseSensor_IG.zip) supplied by the manufacturer.  There is little point in repeating some subset of that data here. Interlink document P/N: EIG-10003

Answer (score 0):

If the supplier offers no advice, I would apply the conductive glue over an organic gold plated ground plane for shielding the signals and apply the rubber and steel clamp to the board.

> Heat generated during the soldering of components can damage the FSR. Therefore, the sensor should not be mounted until PCB assembly is complete. When laminating the FSR to the PCB, be sure to use a hard roller or other depression tool to ensure proper bonding of the sensor’s pressure-sensitive adhesive and the removal of any air bubbles.

The laminate thickness and finger width data can be used to explore possible FPC SMT connectors.

They ought to also supply interface specs for conductance of the 4 quadrant touchpad.

I would think the interface is much like that of a joystick with dual pots except these are printed carbon conductors under the button with some range and centre offset for resistance.

Design sub-PCB as part of a small breakaway or routed panel or mainboard with suitable 0.1" fingers spaced perhaps using *organic gold plating* for the smoothest finish and seal oxygen out from oxidation yet allow mechanical pressure contacts.

[Docs](https://www.interlinkelectronics.com/request-integration-guides)
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is the Moderators who should set a good example. A better answer comes from making a better question. right? @ElliotAlderson  If people can't google any common public datasheet where it doesn't matter where, how can YOU help them by a change on the input checklist?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - Hi, From a (now deleted) comment exchange here, it seems you might misunderstand the site rules, so I thought I should briefly clarify. The current rule on [referencing any resources used in an answer](/help/referencing) applies only to answers, not to questions. You can see this both by the rule's text (i.e. "When you find a useful resource that can help **answer** a question") and by the section in the [help] (i.e. "Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange - Help center - **Answering**"). So you cannot force an OP's question to comply with a rule that applies to *answers*.

Comment: [continued] Personally, I think a rule like that *should* apply to questions too. However, as well as referencing resources in questions not being the actual site rule, I can see some practical problems with trying to implement such a change. In any case, the point is that requiring references in answers here is the responsibility of each answer's author, to avoid possible action for plagiarism and breaking that site rule. I hope that clarifies why you can't point at the OP in this case. (You can raise the topic on Meta.SE if you want to discuss further.)

Comment: Further, you have already been told to stop being unkind to moderators by snide comments, that we might not even see, but which others will see. You are repeatedly breaking the [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) by that behaviour. Please stop.